# getting started with SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I bought [Microsoft SQL Server 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626049) and have been trying to get it set up, but it always seems like any instructions is missing a critical component. For instance:

> **Create Service Accounts**
>
> 1. click start, right-click My Computer, and select Manage
> 2. Expand **Local Users and Groups, and select Users**

I don't have anything saying "local users and groups! I've googled a dozen different "instructions" and "step-by-step guides" which are long on describing what the stupid program does, but very short on telling me how to set it up.
Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a screenshot taken in Windows 8 but it should be the same for older versions as well.
[image: Windows 8 - Computer management]

There is another way to get to this window:

1. Press <kbd>[image]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type: lusrmgr.msc

Comment: right... the stuff in that rectangle *doesn't* exist.

Comment: @ZachFolwick Which edition of Windows do you have?

Comment: I have windows 7 home premium.  It appears I get this error when using @Danny Beckett's lusrmgr.msc suggestion:

https://pcbx.us/akdb.png

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong edition of Windows. But when I install SQL Server I just select the local system account. I have never created a user just for SQL server. Obviously you shouldn't do that in production.